# Can I use CloudFlare DNS without using their service and point DNS to Incapsula?

Tags: dns, cdn, cloudflare

I have been using CloudFlare for a few years as well as Incapsula and while CloudFlare excels in CDN, it is far far far behind in terms of security. Incapsula on the other hand rocks for security (at least for me). Anyway, I have been planning on using Amazon Route 53 DNS and Incapsula CDN n Security services. However, upon researching, Route 53 seems to be a very slow DNS. I checked from at least 5 different DNS performance testing companies and using data over several months, Route 53 response times are about 50ms and CloudFlare (and Dyn) are about 5ms. That is a massive difference.

My query is that is it possible to keep using CloudFlare DNS without CloudFlare services (which I know is possible) and point my A record to Incapsula to use their CDN + Security?

P.S. Incapsula doesn't have DNS on Business plans.

Comment: Why would you think it isn't possible? Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what Incapsula is so might be missing something. But in your cloudflare DNS settings page, for each A/AAAA record you have, you can click on the cloud icon to the right. If its Orange its being proxied the through cloudflare, if its grey, then its not being proxied and all requests will go straight to the origin server.